# Проблема с Tomcat - "Приложение было развёрнуто в контекстном пути [/SchoolMaven], но не стартовало"

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, tomcat

Из-за чего может быть такая ошибка

```
OK - Неразвернутое приложение в контексте пути [/SchoolMaven]
    Развертывание на месте на C:\Users\Fallen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SchoolMaven\target\SchoolMaven
    Выполняется развертывание...
    deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FFallen%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext3285273547592175075.xml&path=/SchoolMaven
    ОШИБКА - Приложение было развёрнуто в контекстном пути [/SchoolMaven], но не стартовало
```

Вот коды

Controller

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    private final static File UPLOAD_FOLDER = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/avatars/");

    static {
        if (!UPLOAD_FOLDER.exists()) {
            UPLOAD_FOLDER.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setSurname(name);
            student.setAvatar(file.getBytes());
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void image(@RequestParam String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(url);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isSaved = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (!isSaved) {

            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean isDeleted = studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        System.out.println("Удаление студента: " + isDeleted);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

Add Student JSP

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="add">
            <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <br>
        <center>
        <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

            <form:form method="POST" action="/addStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label path="Name">Имя</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label path="Surname">Фамилия</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="surname"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label path="Avatar">Фотография:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Добавить"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
    </center>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>

All Student JSP

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>
<title>Все студенты</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <div class="it">
    <h3>Список всех студентов</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>

      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Фото</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>
                     <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${student.base64Image}" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" /></td>

                     <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Редактировать</button>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Удалить</button>



                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить студента</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ошибка в логе

```
29-Apr-2019 15:19:31.820 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

29-Apr-2019 15:19:31.820 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
29-Apr-2019 15:19:31.883 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Нет разрешения на папку, не создался файл, не существует директория... Почитайте catalina.out

Comment: Я правил вопрос добавил коды можете посмотреть где ошибка

Comment: Так причем тут код? я ж вас про catalina.out спросил. Это полный лог томката. и в других логах что написано по поводу этой ошибке?

Comment: Правил вопрос сверху

Comment: Из предоставленных логов, у вас как минимум 2 ошибки.
**Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".** и **mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup**.  Большего, по предоставленным логам, я сказать не могу